# search in a split a sentence in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have a list L created as:

```
atomic_list_concat(L,' ', 'This is a string').

L = ['This',is,a,string]
```

Now I want to search an atom in L using member function. 
I tried :

```
?- member(' is',L).
L = [' is'|_G268] .

?- member( is,L).
L = [is|_G268] .
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the solution posted by [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) is correct, it somewhat breaks the interactive nature of using the Prolog top-level. Typically, you want to base your next query on the previous solution.

For this reason it is possible to [reuse top-level bindings](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=topvars) by writing `$Var` where `Var` is the name of a variable used in a previous query.

In your case:

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', 'This is a string').
L = ['This', is, a, string].
?- member(' is', $L).
false.
?- member('is', $L).
true ;
false.
```

PS: Notice that you would not get a result when searching for `' is'` since separators are removed by [`atomic_list_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3).

Answer (score 1):

Prolog predicates that you run interactively do not carry the state. When you run

```
atomic_list_concat(L,' ', 'This is a string').
```

the interpreter shows you an assignment for `L`, and then forgets its value. When you run `member/2` on the next line, `L` is back to its free variable state.

If you want the same `L` to carry over, you need to stay within the same request, like this:

```
:- atomic_list_concat(L,' ', 'This is a string'),
   member(is, L),
   writeln('membership is confirmed').
```

Now `L` assignment from `atomic_list_concat` is available to `member/2`, letting it check the membership.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks again, I am new to prolog and stackoverflow. So any tip is useful. 
I have another question but I believe I cannot tag specific users for answers. Can I?

Comment: I have posted another question related to prolog. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258188/prolog-eliminating-cycles-from-indirect-relation 
please take a look.