# Prolog : eliminating cycles from indirect relation

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I have a list of user facts defined as:

```
user(@michael).
user(@ana).
user(@bob).
user(@george).
user(@john).
```

and so on. Furthermore, I have a set of facts as:

```
follows(@michael,@ana).
follows(@ana,@bob).
follows(@bob,@michael).
```

I am trying to write a relation indirect(user1,user1) which will tell me if user1 indirectly follows user2. 
However, I am not able to do away with cyclic relations.

Like in the given example, michael -> ana -> bob -> michael will cause a cycle.

What is the best way to eliminate these cycles from the result of indirect(user1,user2)?

Comment: Why do you prefix names with `@`?

Comment: @false, I am trying to create twitter using prolog and one of the rules given to me is that user name starts with @.

Comment: Try `write_canonical(@abx).` it gives `@(abx)`. That is, `@` is a prefix-operator (of SWI). If you really want `@` in names write `'@name'`

Comment: I would try that. Thanks @false. I have posted another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275378/list-processing-in-prolog . Any help or hint would work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a rule that passes an extra list of users that you have "seen" so far, and ignore follows originating from these users: `follows(A, B, Seen)`.

To do that, define a "follow transitive" rule that wraps the actual rule, like this:

```
follows_tx(A, B) :- follows(A, B, []).
```

Now you can define `follows/3` rule this way:

```
follows(A, B, Seen) :-
    not_member(B, Seen),
    follows(A, B).
follows(A, B, Seen) :-
    follows(A, X),
    not_member(X, Seen),
    follows(X, B, [A|Seen]).
```

The base clause says that if there is a fact about `A` following `B`, we consider the predicate proven as long as we have not seen `B` before.

Otherwise, we find someone who follows `A`, check that we have not seen that user yet by checking `not_member/2`, and finally see if that user follows `B`, directly or indirectly.

Finally, here is how you can define `not_member`:

```
not_member(_, []).
not_member(X, [H|T]) :- dif(X, H), not_member(X, T).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/5fhUDk)

Comment: Now, `follows(A,B)` has three solutions only. That's why `(\=)/2` in `not_member/2` is not a good idea.

Comment: @na899 You are welcome! Take a look at the last edit in response to the last comment by false (replacing `=\` with `dif/2`).

Comment: @false Thanks again, I have forgotten how tricky Prolog can be at times (I last programmed in Prolog 20 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

```
indirect( A0,A) :-
   closure(follows, A0,A).
```

See [for a definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) of `closure/3`.