# Predicate must be true of all elements in a list

Tags: prolog

I have a set of facts:

```
likes(john,mary).
likes(mary,robert).
likes(robert,kate).
likes(alan,george).
likes(alan,mary).
likes(george,mary).
likes(harry,mary).
likes(john,alan).
```

Now I want to write a relation which will check for all element X of an input list if `likes(X,A)` is true. my relation should return true once if `likes(X,A)` is true for all element X in my list L.
If I try this this:

```
relat(X) :- member(A,[john,alan,george,harry]), likes(A,X).
```

but the output is

```
?- relat(mary).
true ;
true ;
true ;
true.
```

I want to write it such that it returns one true once it found that `likes(john,mary),likes(alan,mary),likes(george,mary),likes(harry,mary)` all are true.
How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use `forall/2`:

```
?- forall(member(A, [john, alan, george, harry]), likes(A, mary)).
true.
?- forall(member(A, [john,alan,george,harry,marys_ex]), likes(A, mary)).
false.
```

Comment: that was a straight forward solution. I was not educated about forall/2. Thanks @larsmans.

Comment: I find SWI-Prolog's reference manual hard to understand. This example is vastly more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `library(lambda)`:

```
liked_byall(X, Ps) :-
   maplist(X+\P^likes(P,X), Ps).
```

Equally without lambdas:

```
liked_byall(X, Ps) :-
   maplist(liked(X), Ps).

liked(X, P) :-
   likes(P, X).
```

Equally:

```
liked_byall(_X, []).
liked_byall(X, [P|Ps]) :-
   likes(P, X),
   liked_byall(X, Ps).
```

With above definitions you can ask even more general questions like "Who is liked by certain persons?"

```
?- liked_byall(N,[john, alan, george, harry]).
   N = mary
;  false.
```

With the following definition these general questions are no longer possible.

```
liked_byall(X, Ps) :-
   \+ ( member(P, Ps), \+ likes(P, X) ).
```

This second definition only makes sense if `X` is ground and `Ps` is a ground list. We can ensure this as follows:

```
liked_byall(X, Ps) :-
   ( ground(X+Ps) -> true ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ),
   length(Ps,_),
   \+ ( member(P, Ps), \+ likes(P, X) ).
```

These extra checks ensure that absurd cases as the following do not succeed:

```
 ?- liked_byall(mary, nonlist).
```

And that otherwise legitimate cases do not produce an incorrect answer:

```
 ?- liked_byall(N,[john, alan, george, harry]), N = the_grinch.
    N = the_grinch.
```

Answer (score 2):

With standard list processing you can do the following:

```
helper(X, []).                                    % No one left to check
helper(X, [H|L]) :- likes(H, X), helper(X, L).    % Check head, then rest

relat(X) :- helper(X, [john,alan,george,harry]).
```

Demo:

```
| ?- relat(harry).

no
| ?- relat(mary). 

true ? ;

no
| ?-
```